# ZF2 plugin return value gives a Object could not be converted to string

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I build my own plugin just for learning the Framework. It just returns a date(). I get an error in my view when I try to echo it. Its not that hard to understand the error, but what is hard (or at least, what I think is hard) is how I should return it from the plugin so my view (and eventually later other views) don't need any extra information as just pluginReturn?>

The plugin is registered in module.config.php (and it works, else I wouldn't have an error).

Well, some code:

Plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Tijdmachine\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class TellTheTime extends AbstractPlugin{
    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function giveMyTime(){
        return date('H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Lines from Controller involved:

```
$plugin = $this->TellTheTime();
        $plugin->giveMyTime();

        $views = new ViewModel(array('text' => 'Het is nu de tijd.', 'pluginReturn' => $plugin));
```

View line:

```
<?=$this->pluginReturn?>
```

The error I'm getting: 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Tijdmachine\Controller\Plugin\TellTheTime could not be converted to string in /home/snoech/code/zftuts/trunk/module/Tijdmachine/view/tijdmachine/index/index.phtml on line 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$plugin` contain the object. Re-assign the value in a variable and give it to the view:

```
$plugin = $this->TellTheTime();
$myDate = $plugin->giveMyTime();
$views = new ViewModel(array('text' => 'Het is nu de tijd.', 'pluginReturn' => $myDate));
```

**or**

```
$plugin = $this->TellTheTime();
$views = new ViewModel(array('text' => 'Het is nu de tijd.', 'pluginReturn' => $plugin->giveMyTime()));
```

Comment: I may not and will not swear on this website, but I for sure should have seen that. This are just the hickups of a fridayafternoon. But indeed, this is the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. End of the week is coming soon, keep it positive :). Edit: Btw if it's fine think to close this issue.